# LOL..still at 98 rep and 100 rep prievileges are open to me?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Seems the system got tired of waiting in the 90's for me. I got notifications that I have been given two new prievileges (they need 100 rep), while I can see my rep never climbed above 98.

P.S - This is just FYI for any RCA if needed...am not complaining so please dont take away my prievileges. :)

Comment: Be sure to tick "show removed posts" in your reputation overview. Most likely there was just a post you gained rep on that has since been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Take away the priviliges! *just kidding*, maybe... [Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold)

Anyways, it just takes a bit of time to take effect I think.